# Why does not this expression work?

Tags: sql, expression

everyone. I want the crm system to Return all Pledge donors with role number 1600, 1700 and 1800 that has not attrited (tildato= attrited)

```
(aktorid from fadderskap where rollenr = 1600
or aktorid from fadderskap where rollenr = 1700
or aktorid from fadderskap where rollenr = 1800)
and nvl(tildato, trunc(sysdate) + 1) >= trunc(sysdate)
```

Comment: What CRM are you using, and should you be writing the expressions in SQL or some other language expected by your CRM?

Comment: Please read a book or anarticle on constructing select statements. SQL is a language with a fixed syntax, it does not understand syntax that you are trying to invent.

Comment: SQL queries traditionally start with the keyword `SELECT`.  Please post your entire query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you are using some dbms that I haven't heard about, or you have syntax issues.. so try this query instead:

```
aktorid from fadderskap
where rollenr in (1600,1700,1800)
    and nvl(tildato, trunc(sysdate) + 1) >= trunc(sysdate)
```